# How to upgrade smf (simple machine forum) 1.1.6 to 2.0.2?

Tags: upgrade, forum

I have smf forum 1.1.6.I want to change 2.0.2. How to upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check manual updating SMF Forum.

Really easy:

Download 2.0.2 (Update)
unzip
put all files into the root folder.
Overwrite the old ones
run
repair_settings.php

done!

Answer (score 1):

Download the large upgrade package from https://download.simplemachines.org/

Unzip all files to your forum root and execute yourforum.tld/upgrade.php

The answer from @Greeb will not do the job, like changing DB settings!

Before upgrading from SMF 1.x to 2.0.x, be sure you can get the same mods and themes to work with your forum - or find similar solutions that suits you. Many mods for SMF 1 will not work with SMF 2 and *no* theme from SMF 1 will work with SMF 2, unless the theme author specifically made a SMF 2 version!